# Duplicate the input in the form React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have react app.
And some form with input, and I want add button and function, when we click we can add new input in our form.
But I don't know? how I can make it. In native js, I can use create element and appendchild in parent block with some class or id. But in react ((

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Form</h1>
            <form onSubmit = { this.onSubmit } action="/form" method="post">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.first} name="first" autoFocus="autoFocus" onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.second} name="second" onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />
                </div>

                <button onClick={this.handleDouble}>Double</button>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

handleDouble(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You've got to learn to think in React. Your result in React is a function of your data. How could you shape your component state to get what you want? Is this just a single additional input or many additional inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to shape your data to produce the result you want in React.

For example, if I were trying to produce the two inputs you have here, my state would look something like this:

```
this.state = {
    inputs: [{
        name: 'first',
        autoFocus: true,
        type: 'text',
        value: '1'
    }, {
        name: 'second',
        autoFocus: false,
        type: 'text',
        value: '2'
    }]
};
```

Then in my `render()` function, I would do something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Form</h1>
            <form onSubmit = { this.onSubmit } action="/form" method="post">
                <div>
                   {
                       this.state.inputs.map((input) => (
                           <input type={input.type} value={input.value} name={input.name} autoFocus={input.autoFocus} onChange={this.handleInputOnChange} />
                       );
                   }
                </div>

                <button onClick={this.handleDouble}>Double</button>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This would produce 1 input **for each** index of `this.state.inputs`.

Comment: You can reduce the length of the input line using spread syntax: `<input {...input} onChange={this.handleInputOnChange} />`

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind this only works if the name of your properties inside of `this.state.input` are the same as your `<input>` component takes. Otherwise, you would need to explicitly list them. For instance, if `input.autoFocus` were `input.hasAutoFocus` you would need: `<input {...input} autoFocus={input.hasAutoFocus} />`. Although, it's arguably easier (and better practice) to just change the name of the property in the state. Just noted for future people who may not fully understand the spread operator.